# Setting data chart color - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use a background image as a color for one data point and a HEX color for another but it's not working.

Here is my series:

```
        series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        innerSize: '50%',
        data: [{
         y: iG,            
         color: {
            pattern: 'http://sp2007/Style%20Library/pattern.png',
            width: 6,
            height: 6
            }
         },
         { 
          y: s, color: '#00ADEF'
          }],
    }]
```

For some reason the chart refuse to render after adding the color property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by referencing pattern-fill.js

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/highslide-software/pattern-fill/master/pattern-fill.js"></script>
```